# 802.1x computer authentication using hostname instead of cert

Tags: networking, authentication, 802.1

My configuration includes: Cisco ACS as RADIUS server, MS AD, MS PKI, Cisco 2960G switches. Workstations are 95% XP Pro SP3 fully patched, some 7 pro fully patched. 
Computer cert autoenrollment enabled and working.
GPO for [image: wired dot1x settings]

Resulting NIC settings from GPO on workstation:
[image]

Port configuration on the switches is as follows:
 switchport access vlan 56
 switchport mode access
 authentication control-direction in
 authentication event fail action authorize vlan 66
 authentication event server dead action reinitialize vlan 56
 authentication event no-response action authorize vlan 66
 authentication event server alive action reinitialize
 authentication host-mode multi-auth
 authentication port-control auto
 authentication violation protect
 mab
 dot1x pae authenticator
 spanning-tree portfast

The problem I'm having is that as machines are booting up, they are attempting to authenticate with their hostname rather than certificate. This fails but then a minute later, they use the computer certificate and authentication is successful. The configuration is working (mostly) but every once in a while I get a computer (about 250 setup for dot1x so far) that tries to authenticate with its hostname which fails and then stops. If I restart the wired autoconfig service, it authenticates perfectly but rebooting re-creates the problem.
[image]
It is also very annoying that these errors show up in the logs because the frequency of them prevents me from setting up alerts to notify me when an actual unauthorized computer has been connected to the network. i.e. too many false positives.
My question is why does the workstation attempt to authenticate with its hostname first when I have configured it to use its computer certificate?

 On the wireless side, everything is working perfectly. Cisco AP's and WLCs.
EDIT* I found a hotfix KB957931 that indicates that XP SP3 will ignore dot1x traffic for 20 minutes after receiving an authentication failure message. The hotfix allows you to create a registry key to modify this previously hard-coded setting. I applied the patch to a workstation and changed the blocktime to 1 minute (the minimum) and now, after a minute the workstation does authenticate but does not renew its IP. The one minute wait is not ideal nor is dealing with renewing the IP so I am still good with the original question which is why does the box choose to identify itself with its name instead of its certificate?

**UPDATE* 1/11/12** I ran into this problem again today and poked around the client some. I noticed that in the authentication tab on the local area network connection, the settings were no longer grayed out and were changed to use passwords rather than certificates. I know local group policy is applied at boot up no matter if the PC belongs to a domain or not and I know that my domain GPO overrides whatever is set locally. When the PC fails to authenticate for some reason (power failure of network gear in this case) it no longer applies the domain policies and apparently my settings all get changed. I'm not sure why they are changing since no local GPO's were ever configured.
So, in addition to wanting to know why PC's identify themselves with their hostname before using their certificate I now have a second question.
How do I create a local group policy on XP workstations with the dot1x settings (they are missing from the default templates available) and how can I push those out to all my workstations? I've looked into using security templates but they do not contain the settings I need. I need to apply settings from Computer Config -> Policies -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> System Services. That last bit is missing from both local GPO's on XP and also from the SCA snap-in.
It should be noted that I already have a domain GPO that works perfectly. Isn't there an easy way to export this and apply it as the local GPO for each workstation?
Full points will be rewarded for an answer to either question.

Comment: Any chance you can get some captured packets from an AP between the mobile client & radius server?  (at the AP would be ideal)  Maybe there's some sort of network bottleneck where the client sends RADIUS auth... but before it gets the successful auth back... it sends the hostname for auth.

Comment: Wireless is working fine. The problem only occurs on the wired network. I have done some captures and see the PC responding to EAPOL with its hostname for identity (which fails). On most machines, a minute or so later they respond with their certificate which then succeeds but not all of them are doing so. The problem workstations never respond again and sit there unauthorized and they only do this once every 2 weeks. Very random and very annoying.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for certain that this is the solution, but I'm thinking that in the reboot process, the machine is trying to log on "too soon," before the other services that allow support for using the certificate instead of the hostname.  Perhaps try setting the Netlogon service to "Automatic (Delayed Start)"?

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much what I was thinking but I really want to know how that process works and how to avoid it without creating additional "wait time". Also, seems that delayed start is not an option in XP (95% of my workstations). Is there an add-on to enable this for XP? I could create a dependency on another service but which service handles certificates?

Comment: I modified the netlogon service to depend on the Cryptography Service and there was no change in the ACS log. It still identified as the hostname of the box then 91 seconds later, used the certificate. By the way, I'm seeing the cert auth 91-100 seconds later every time (except when it never tries again).

Comment: If this is the case, I'm looking for documentation that supports it so that I can figure out a workaround since what I tried failed to function appropriately.